# Proof by induction help

Tags: recursion

I don't know the full process of induction, as it's one of the harder questions on my upcoming test papers I thought i'd attempt to get a basic understanding; in order to get a 1/2 marks out of the question. However, since doing it I believe with a bit of help I could get full marks. Here's my attempt, I know it's not great but.. if someone could point me in the right direction of where i'm going wrong, i'd be most grateful.

***I know I have posted the same question above, but the difference being today I've actually attempted it using a method I found on google so would like someone to take a look***

> $\text{b)}$ Consider the function $\rm take:\mathbf N\to\mathbf N$ defined recursively as follows:
>
> $\qquad1)$ **Base case:** $\,\,\rm take(0)=100$
>   $\qquad2)$ **Recursive case:** $\,\,\,\rm for \,\,any\,\,x\gt0,\,\,\, take (x)=take(x-1)-2$
>
> Prove using *induction on the natural numbers* that the following equality is true for all natural numbers $\rm n\in\mathbf N$: $$\rm take(n)=100-(2*n)$$

take (0) = 100
for any x>0, take(x)=take(x-1)-2

take(n)=100-(2*n)

1) 1>0 take(1)=  take(1-1)-2

show true for n=1

take(0)=100
take(1)=take(1-1)-2
       =take(0)-2
       =100-2
       =98

Assume it's true for n=k

take(k)=take(k-k)-2  = true

therefore

- take(k+1)=take(k+1-2)-2 = true
- take(1+1)=take(k)-2
- take(2)=take(1)-2
- take(2) = take(k)-2 due to our assumption
- take(k)=take(k-k)-2
- take(2)=take(k-k)-2

at the end I've got no idea where I was going with it tbh...

Answer (score 1):

You make the inductive assumption that $\;T(n)=100-2n\;$ , with $\;T=$ the "take" function, and then you must prove it for $\;n+1\;$ :

$$T(n+1):\stackrel{\text{By def.}}= T(n)-2\stackrel{\text{Ind. Hypothesis}}=\left[100-(2n)\right]-2=100-2(n+1)$$

and the rigthmost expression is **exactly** what it must be when using $\;n+1\;$ instead of $\;n\;$ in the definition of $\;T\;$ , so we're done!

Comment: Wait, so what I've put would get me like 9/10 marks??

Comment: I really didn't read what you did, @user118964: it is too tough for me to decypher the way it is typed, but even if I did I cannot possibly know what mark would it get it as I am not your teacher.

Comment: oh you was joking them, damn it : (

Comment: What? "Joking them"? Beats me...

Comment: @user118964  (1) When was I joking and what about? (2) Are you calling me an idiot?